# which is the best way to create a custom error page in sharepoint ?

Tags: 2007, custom, error.htm

Which is the best way to create a custom error page in SharePoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "best". The easiest way: In your web.config file: in the <system.web> section, modify the customErrors element to:

<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Pages/MyCustomErrorPage.aspx" />

Comment: i mean , i dont want standard sharepoint error page"page not found" page to come everytime . i need to have an error page designed seperately for my client and whenever there is any error the custom page shld be soming .

Comment: The 404 page not found situation is a little different. First you need to modify the FileNotFoundPage of the SPWebApplication object and give it a new file name, which you can code in a feature or do with Powershell. SharePoint looks for this 404 page in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033 (assuming English locale) - you can't give it a full path or URL.

Answer (score 0):

Write a HttpModule to handle the onerror event, and redirect to the custom error page.